# How to run a javascript inside of Bobik and return a JSON

Tags: javascript, android, json, web-scraping

I'm very tired of web-scraping in my Android app. It takes too long, it is very unstable: sometimes it is fast, sometimes it is slow, sometimes it freezes and eats so much traffic.

So the best thing that I have found out is Bobik. It takes care of everything and then you got only a JSON. But I have one problem: my page contains a javascript that runs and only afterwards I have the information that I need to extract.

In their examples, they have html page with google.com , expedia.com with JSON like `//title //h1 //img/@src`

But, for example, this page: http://www.washington.edu/calendar/ does not contain anything parameters that I need. Its html does not have `time`, `event_name` and `location`, so how do I run javascript?

Or should I just say what I want and Bobik team will take care of the rest?

Comment: machine-formatted data like http://www.trumba.com/calendars/sea_campus.rss is easier to consume

Comment: you might look into YQL's data modules as well, html is a possible source

Comment: The problem is that rss page is huge and uncomfortable to manipulate. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: RSS will be much simpler and more reliable to parse than scraping a webpage would, especially if that webpage doesn't have the info you need...